# Dual channel of ram with mismatch size

Tags: laptop, memory, performance

My laptop have 2GB Ram because i have two ram sloths  want to add more. But Before I add more ram. I want know that i have bought a 4GB of ram. without thinking and knowing about dual channel of ram. i many websites it has written that for enabling dual channel of ram. Both chips must match. But luckily i got every thing same in my both ram chips (2gb in laptop and 4gb outside). The spec of both RAM Modules are:

```
          RAN in laptop(2gb)                     RAM Bought(4gb)
```

Manufacturer   Micro technology ------------------------  Crucial Technology

Frequenccy    1600MHz ------------------------------------1600MHz

Max bandwitch PC3-12800(800MHz)------------------------- PC3-12800(800MHz)

VOL           1.35v -------------------------------------------------------- 1.35V

Form factor   SO-DIMM---------------------------------------- SO-DIMM

Type          DDR3----------------------------------------- DDR3

Memory type   SDRAM ---------------------------------------- SDRAM

Size          2GB -------------------------------------------- 4GB

DRAM Frequency  798.1 MHz---------------------------------- 798.1MHz

CAS# Latency (CL)   11 clocks -------------------------- 11 Clocks

RAS# to CAS# Delay (tRCD)    11 clocks----------------------- 11 clocks

RAS# Precharge (tRP)    11 clocks  -------------------------- 11 clocks

Cycle Time (tRAS)   28 clocks ----------------------------- 28 clocks

Command Rate (CR)   1T --------------------------------------- 1T

Every thing is same but size is not same my question is if i add another 4gb ram in my laptop will i get 6gb dual channel ram. or this may damage my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this will not damage the system

As long as the RAM is compatible it will recognize

If they were of different frequency it would have decreased the frequency of the higher frequency to match lower frequency

But in your case they both are identical and differ only in size so you would be able to see 6GB total

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. as you answered I insert that memory module in my laptop. i got  6gb ram running on dual channel. my Graphics memory increase by double. reserved ram also go down by 311mb to 105mb